# Is at least half of the elements of even order in a finite group of even order?

Tags: group-theory

This is true for finite abelian groups, according to the structure theorem:

$G\simeq \left(\bigoplus_{i}\mathbb{Z}_{2^{n_i}}\right) \bigoplus \left( \bigoplus_{j} \mathbb{Z}_{p_j ^{m_j}} \right)$

Any element $a\oplus b$ with $a$ non-trivial is of even order. If the first part is non-trivial, the percentage of such elements is at least 50.

But is it true for general finite groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not generally true.  For instance, in the alternating group $A_5$, there are:

- 1 element of order 1
- 15 elements of order 2
- 20 elements of order 3
- 24 elements of order 5